# raw_input python

Tags: python

So I'm a really young programmer, I use python, and I'm trying to make a application in python that tracks my chores, when you finish the login, like when you login as me, when your done, it quits it, I want my parents to be able to look at that stuff, thats why there is a login, I want it to be where when the variables are empty, and your on my parents login, it says that there is nothing in the variables, and ask you to put something in the variables, I also want so that when my profile is over, it asks for a login again, here is the code.(I have taken my name out of the code, for privacy.)

```
print ("Welcome to Chore Tracker, ")

name = raw_input("Who is this?")

if name == "******": 
    c1 = raw_input("Have you kept your room clean?")
    c2 = raw_input("Did you fed IVAN?")
    c3 = raw_input("Have you fed your hamster?")
    c4 = raw_input("How many bags of trash have you taken out?")
    print "If you did all of those things, you have 6 dollars, plus " +     c4 + ", dollars!"
    print "If you did two of those things, you have 4 dollars, plus " + c4 + ", dollars!"
    print "If you did only one thing, you have two dollars, plus " + c4 + ", dollars!"

elif name == "Mom":
    print("Hello, Mom!, if an error pops up, that means I didn't put anything down yet!")
    print "Room clean, " + c1
    print "IVAN fed, " + c2
    print "Hamster fed, " + c3
    print "And I took out, " + c4 + ", bags of trash!"
    print "So I have 2, 4, or 6 dollars, plus, " + c4 + ", dollars!"

else:
    print("Hello, Dad!, if an error pops up, that means I didn't put anything down yet!")
    print "Room clean, " + c1
    print "IVAN fed, " + c2
    print "Hamster fed, " + c3
    print "And I took out, " + c4 + ", bags of trash!"
    print "So I have 2, 4, or 6 dollars, plus, " + c4 + ", dollars!"
```

Answer (score 0):

if-elif-else is often called a "branching" statement, because at each condition, you choose whether to take that branch of execution.  Therefore, if `name == "******"`, you will only execute that first block and not the `elif` or `else`.  You, however, only declare `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, and `c4` in your first branch but use it in all 3.  You therefore need to move the variable declarations outside of your if-elif-else block so that it is always executed before your if-elif-else block.

Example

```
print ("Welcome to Chore Tracker, ")

name = raw_input("Who is this?")
c1 = raw_input("Have you kept your room clean?")
c2 = raw_input("Did you fed IVAN?")
c3 = raw_input("Have you fed your hamster?")
c4 = raw_input("How many bags of trash have you taken out?")

if name == "******": 
    print "If you did all of those things, you have 6 dollars, plus " +     c4 + ", dollars!"
    print "If you did two of those things, you have 4 dollars, plus " + c4 + ", dollars!"
    print "If you did only one thing, you have two dollars, plus " + c4 + ", dollars!"

elif name == "Mom":
    print("Hello, Mom!, if an error pops up, that means I didn't put anything down yet!")
    print "Room clean, " + c1
    print "IVAN fed, " + c2
    print "Hamster fed, " + c3
    print "And I took out, " + c4 + ", bags of trash!"
    print "So I have 2, 4, or 6 dollars, plus, " + c4 + ", dollars!"

else:
    print("Hello, Dad!, if an error pops up, that means I didn't put anything down yet!")
    print "Room clean, " + c1
    print "IVAN fed, " + c2
    print "Hamster fed, " + c3
    print "And I took out, " + c4 + ", bags of trash!"
    print "So I have 2, 4, or 6 dollars, plus, " + c4 + ", dollars!"
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem at the moment seems to be that

1. Your variables are declared in one of the `if` branches, so it won't be accessible from the rest of the branches
2. Once you quit, (so, say, your mother can login), your variables aren't populated any more.

Assuming you'll keep the program running, (so that 2 isn't a problem), here's what I would recommend:

```
c1 = "No"
c2 = "No"
c3 = "No"
c4 = "0"

def run():
    print ("Welcome to Chore Tracker, ")
    name = raw_input("Who is this?")

    if name == "******": 
        c1 = raw_input("Have you kept your room clean?")
        c2 = raw_input("Did you fed IVAN?")
        c3 = raw_input("Have you fed your hamster?")
        c4 = raw_input("How many bags of trash have you taken out?")
        print "If you did all of those things, you have 6 dollars, plus " +     c4 + ", dollars!"
        print "If you did two of those things, you have 4 dollars, plus " + c4 + ", dollars!"
        print "If you did only one thing, you have two dollars, plus " + c4 + ", dollars!"

    elif name == "Mom":
        print("Hello, Mom!, if an error pops up, that means I didn't put anything down yet!")
        print "Room clean, " + c1
        print "IVAN fed, " + c2
        print "Hamster fed, " + c3
        print "And I took out, " + c4 + ", bags of trash!"
        print "So I have 2, 4, or 6 dollars, plus, " + c4 + ", dollars!"

    else:
        print("Hello, Dad!, if an error pops up, that means I didn't put anything down yet!")
        print "Room clean, " + c1
        print "IVAN fed, " + c2
        print "Hamster fed, " + c3
        print "And I took out, " + c4 + ", bags of trash!"
        print "So I have 2, 4, or 6 dollars, plus, " + c4 + ", dollars!"


while True:
    run()
```

The starting initializations mean that your program won't throw an error, and present the current state before you login.

The infinite `while` loop will make sure that your program asks for login again after a user is done.